Gitlab, empty volume after execute jobs
I have two containers of a service:

app (container 1)
celery (container 2)
It's two docker compose files. I also have manual jobs for each container in gitlab.
Both containers have the same volumes.

For example, I start jobs in this order: container 1 -> container 2.
After that, volumes in container 1 are unavailable, but in container 2 - everything is ok.
If I start jobs in the order: container 2 -> container 1, then volumes in container 2 are unavailable, but in container 1 - everything is ok.
What could be the problem?
Docker-compose 1 container:
version: "3.9"

volumes:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
  logs_volume:

networks:
  reservation_net:
    external: true

services:
  api_1:
    image: reservation_api_1
    container_name: reservation_api_1
    entrypoint: ["/bin/bash","./start_server.sh"]
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/api_1/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/api/
      - static_volume:/api/static
      - media_volume:/api/media
      - logs_volume:/api/logs
    networks:
      - reservation_net

Docker-compose 2 container:
version: "3.9"

volumes:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
  logs_volume:

networks:
  reservation_net:
    external: true

services:
  celery:
    image: reservation_celery
    container_name: reservation_celery
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/celery/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    command: celery -A hs_reservation worker -B -c 2 --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/api/
      - static_volume:/api/static
      - media_volume:/api/media
      - logs_volume:/api/logs
    networks:
      - reservation_net

gitlab-ci:
deploy_api:
  script:
    - !reference [.api_variables, script]
    - sudo docker-compose -f compose-dev-api.yaml down
    - sudo docker-compose -f compose-dev-api.yaml up -d --build
  when: manual
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - Dev
  tags:
    - tms-dev


deploy_celery:
  when: manual
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - !reference [.api_variables, script]
  - sudo docker-compose -f compose-dev-celery.yaml down
  - sudo docker-compose -f compose-dev-celery.yaml up -d --build
  only:
  - Dev
  tags:
  - tms-dev

Here is the console output, which should illustrate my point.
root@tms-dev:~# docker ps

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                                      NAMES
7d34ad566d73   reservation_celery     "celery -A hs_reserv…"   18 minutes ago   Up 18 minutes                                                                              reservation_celery
ad89ec17fb2b   reservation_api_1      "/bin/bash ./start_s…"   19 minutes ago   Up 19 minutes                                                                              reservation_api_1

root@tms-dev:~# docker exec -it reservation_api_1 bash
root@ad89ec17fb2b:/api# ls -a media/
.  ..

root@tms-dev:~# docker exec -it reservation_celery bash
root@7d34ad566d73:/api# ls -a media/
.  ..  addresses  apple_cards  google-loyalty  loyalty_cards  loyalty_cards_v1  reservations  users

root@tms-dev:~# docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' reservation_celery
[{bind  /home/gitlab-runner/builds/298VLqEut/0/hammer_systems/hs_reservation2_backend /api  rw true rprivate} {volume hs_reservation2_backend_media_volume /var/lib/docker/volumes/hs_reservation2_backend_media_volume/_data /api/media local z true }]

root@tms-dev:~# docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' reservation_api_1
[{bind  /home/gitlab-runner/builds/298VLqEut/0/hammer_systems/hs_reservation2_backend /api  rw true rprivate} {volume hs_reservation2_backend_media_volume /var/lib/docker/volumes/hs_reservation2_backend_media_volume/_data /api/media local z true }]
root@tms-dev:~#


What does it mean "volumes are unavailable"? What happens? Do you receive an error message? The docker-compose configurations are similar - docker compose uses namespaces with directory names. If both are in the same named directory, they are both referencing same volumes. Use COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME environmetn varaible or create a different directory to separate two configurations.

This means that when I'm in the container, the Media and Static folders are empty.

The volume mounts hide everything in the original image, and I wouldn't usually recommend mounting a volume over your application's static-content directory.  If you reconfigure logs to go to stdout and not a file, and you COPY your application code into the image, can you delete the volumes: block entirely?

I can't delete volumes. What should I do with media and static?

An empty folder is unrelated to mount existence. So is it mounted? Please check mount or /proc/mtab or mountpoint command. | What happens when you try to delete volumes? Please post the full all error and other messages.

Please see, I have edited the question.

Hi. As i unerstand tge issue is that there are two different services in different docker composes have different content in two different volumes? Why isn't it one docker compose file? If the volume shouldn't be managed by one of dockercomposes, it needs to be external, no? Something may be mounred over the directory, or it may be unmounted. You could try to confirm with nount from inside containers and maybe also from host that both are mounted to the same destination.

Waut a sec you are mounting  - .:/api/ and then overmounting subdirectories? Do you expect it to work? How is that supposed to work? What do you expect to happen when gitlab decides to  remove build files? I would guess the subdirectory is obscured by the api mount.

I have the same folder mounted to two different servers (2 different docker files). And in one container the content of this folder is displayed, in the other one it is empty. As you can see, there is the same path in both containers...
/var/lib/docker/volumes/hs_reservation2_backend_media_volume/_data

I would normally expect docker-compose -f compose-dev-celery.yaml up to stop the api_1 container, since it's part of the current Compose project but not listed in the Compose file.  What sequence of commands leads to it actually running?  This is significantly more complicated for being in two Compose files; can you combine them into one?  (As above, you can probably delete the volumes entirely, and you should also be able to delete the custom network and the image: and container_name: overrides.)
